# reduce the size of speed in packet payload

Tags: c, performance, byte, packet, mavlink

How can I reduce the size of speed data from 4-bytes to 2-bytes in C.
I have a packet payload of 41-bytes I reduced some data and now I have 39-bytes where I want my packet payload to be 36-byte.

The remaining data that I don't know if there is a possibility to reduce there sizes are:

Drone--> LAT 4-bytes,
LON 4-bytes,
ALT 4-bytes,
Speed 4-bytes

GCS --> LAT 4-bytes,
LON 4-bytes,
ALT 4-bytes,

I have other data that I manged to reduce them to have 39-bytes
and now those are the renaming and wondering if I can reduce more 3-bytes.

Comment: You would need to know the actual range of the values.

Comment: What is this the speed of? Car speeds can fit in 1 byte, since it can hold from 0 to 255, and cars don't go much faster than 100 MPH or 160 KPH.

Comment: And 2 bytes can hold up to more than 65,000. This is enough for the speeds of any terrestrial aircraft.

Comment: @Barmar Don't forget the precision.

Comment: @user58697 Good point. Although if you're dealing with anything flying at subsonic speeds, this is enough for 2 decimal places.

Comment: @BarmarDepends on the application. If you want a drone to land within 10 feet of a target point (only relying on a GPS), you need about 25 bits for a latitude (I do have a hard time estimating the necessary precision of the speed, but I am positive that 2 decimal places would not suffice). Sorry for being anal.